# Create a mask both for nan and inf values in an array

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have to remove both nan and inf values from two arrays.
I found this post useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/48591908/7541421 for removing nan. Is there any similar solution when I can create a mask to remove both nan and inf values?

The example below is just illustrative, I have arrays of large dimensions (400 elements)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan, inf

a = np.asarray([0.5, 6.2, np.nan, 4.5, np.inf])
b = np.asarray([np.inf, np.inf, 0.3, np.nan, 0.5])

bad = ~np.logical_or(np.isnan(a), np.isnan(b))

X = np.compress(bad, a)  
Y = np.compress(bad, b) 

BIAS = np.nanmean(X - Y)
RMSE = np.sqrt(np.nanmean((X - Y)**2))
CORR = np.corrcoef(X, Y)
```

I need this in order to get both the statistics and plots correctly

Comment: Use `np.isinf` and `np.isnan`?

Comment: no, those arrays are quite short just as an example. It's a huge dataset. I need to remove a whole lot of them from each array of 400 elements

Comment: instead of (or in addition to) linking to another question, post the code you're using.

Comment: Seems like an [`XY problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.isfinite`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html)

> Test element-wise for finiteness (not infinity or not Not a Number).

Answer (score 14):

You can use `np.isfinite()`.  It will return a boolean mask with `True` wherever the values are neither infinite nor NAN.

You can get the finite values this way:

```
a = np.asarray(a)
a = a[np.isfinite(a)]
```

Or for both arrays together:

```
mask = np.isfinite(a) | np.isfinite(b)
a = a[mask]
b = b[mask]
```

Comment: OK but how do you then obtain the actual array without the values and not the boolean?

Comment: thank you! Just one further clarification: how can you take into consideration the elements that are good in both arrays, a and b? So to get them both with the same dimension?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine to me.

I created it with this to solve the problem in merge NaN and masked arrays:

```
masked_red_diff = masked_red_diff[np.isfinite(masked_red_diff)]
masked_red_diff.mean()
```