# How to compute the correlations of long format dataframe with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have a dataframe with 3 columns.

```
UserId | ItemId | Rating
```

(where Rating is the rating a User gave to an Item. It's a np.float16. The 2 Id's are np.int32)

How do you best compute correlations **between items** using python pandas?

My take is to first pivot the table (wide format) and then apply pd.corr

```
df = df.pivot(index='UserId', columns='ItemId', values='Rating')
df.corr()
```

It's working on small datasets, but not on big ones.

That first step creates a big matrix dataset mostly full of missing values. It's quite ram intensive and I can't run it with bigger dataframes.

Isn't there a simpler way to compute the correlations directly on the long dataset, without pivoting?

(I looked into pd.groupBy, but that seems to only split the dataframe, not what I'm looking for.)

EDIT: oversimplified data and working pivot code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'UserId': [1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3], 
     'ItemId': [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3], 
     'Rating': [1.1,4.5,7.1, 5.5,3.1,5.5, 1.1,np.nan,2.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.astype(dtype={'UserId': np.int32, 'ItemId': np.int32, 'Rating': np.float32})
print(df.info())
pivot = df.pivot(index='UserId', columns='ItemId', values='Rating')
print('')
print(pivot)
corr = pivot.corr()
print('')
print(corr)
```

EDIT2: Large random data generator

```
def randDf(size = 100):
  ## MAKE RANDOM DATAFRAME, df =======================
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  import random
  import math
  dict_for_df = {}
  for i in ('UserId','ItemId','Rating'):   
    dict_for_df[i] = {}
    for j in range(size):
      if i=='Rating': val = round( random.random()*5, 1) 
      else: val = round( random.random() * math.sqrt(size/2) )
      dict_for_df[i][j] = val     # store in a dict
  # print(dict_for_df)
  df = pd.DataFrame(dict_for_df) # after the loop convert the dict to a dataframe
  # print(df.head())
  df = df.astype(dtype={'UserId': np.int32, 'ItemId': np.int32, 'Rating': np.float32})
  # df = df.astype(dtype={'UserId': np.int64, 'ItemId': np.int64, 'Rating': np.float64})
  ## remove doubles -----
  df.drop_duplicates(subset=['UserId','ItemId'], keep='first', inplace=True)
  ## show -----
  print(df.info())
  print(df.head())
  return df
# =======================

df = randDf()
```

Comment: Could you provide some example data and expected output, and explain in more detail what you mean by "correlations between items?" Are you interested in finding situations in which, e.g., User A liked Item 1 and also Item 2 (a particular user's ratings for two different products are correlated)? Also, how many total users, items, and ratings do you have? Has each user rated each item exactly once?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Small example added in the question (but data types are not respected). My numbers are ~50k items and ~200k users ~20M ratings. No not "exactly" once: maximum once. (thus once or never)

Answer (score 0):

I had another go, and have something that gets exactly the same correlation numbers as your method without using pivot, but is much slower. I can't say whether it uses less or more memory:

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr   
import itertools
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

d = []    
itemids = list(set(df['ItemId']))
pairsofitems = list(itertools.combinations(itemids,2))

for itempair in pairsofitems:
    a = df[df['ItemId'] == itempair[0]][['Rating', 'UserId']]
    b = df[df['ItemId'] == itempair[1]][['Rating', 'UserId']]

    z = np.ones(len(set(df.UserId)), dtype=int)
    z = z * np.nan
    z[a.UserId.values] = a.Rating.values

    w = np.ones(len(set(df.UserId)), dtype=int)
    w = w * np.nan
    w[b.UserId.values] = b.Rating.values 

    bad = ~np.logical_or(np.isnan(w), np.isnan(z))
    z = np.compress(bad, z)
    w = np.compress(bad, w)
    d.append({'firstitem': itempair[0], 
              'seconditem': itempair[1], 
              'correlation': pearsonr(z,w)[0]})

df_out = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['firstitem', 'seconditem', 'correlation'])
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591713/pearson-correlation-and-nan-values) was of help working out to handle the nan's before taking the correlation.

The slicing in the two lines after the for loop take time.  I think though, it may have potential if the bottlenecks could be fixed.

Yes, there is some repetition in there with the z and w variables, could put that in a function.

Some explanation of what it does:

- find all combinations of pairs within your items
- organise and "x" and "y" set of points for UserId / Rating where any point pair where one of the two is missing (nan) is dropped. I think of a scatter plot and the correlation being how well a straight line fits through it.
- run pearson correlation on this x-y pair
- put the ItemId each pair and correlation into a dataframe