# how to pass a list [ ] with sepcific column values for pearson correlation calculations in Pandas

Tags: correlation

I'm an intro to  Data Science in Python class from Coursera online.  This exercise requires Pearson correlation only for two specific columns.  Attached code is erroring

a) is it because these columns some how have "NaN" value in them - ?
b) is there discrepancy btw an 'int' & 'tuple' is causing this error.

Is error occurs on an auto grader for class assignment
Please provide insights on how correct this.

I've added df.where condition and print value-count , where i see for sure "Nan" are excluded

```
import pandas as pd  # just need to provide corr  
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
a = pd.read_csv('NISPUF17.csv',usecols = ['HAD_CPOX','P_NUMVRC']).dropna()
a = a.query('HAD_CPOX != 77')
print(len(a)) #15286 
#print(a.value_counts().sum()) #15286
# print(a.value_counts())
a.sort_index(inplace=True)
def lengths():
    corr = stats.pearsonr(a[:,0],a[:,1])
    return corr
print(lengths())
```

Comment: please add a code snippet.

Comment: sorry - i edited my question and add code snippet ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no NaN in the columns:

```
import pandas as pd  # just need to provide corr  
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
a = pd.read_csv('NISPUF17.csv',usecols = ['HAD_CPOX','P_NUMVRC']).dropna()
a = a.query('HAD_CPOX != 77')
print(len(a)) #15286 
#print(a.value_counts().sum()) #15286
# print(a.value_counts())
a.sort_index(inplace=True)
# def lengths():
#     corr = stats.pearsonr(a[:,0],a[:,1])
#     return corr
# print(lengths())

a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [0, 0, 1]})

def lengths():
    corr = stats.pearsonr(a['a'],a['b'])
    return corr

print(lengths())
```

If does not work, check:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48591908/1614089

Comment: Oren, Thank you it does.  Appreciate  your help  with  tuple .. thought I had it working with df.a and df.b                                              also, appreciate the other url you listed.